# when api call fails on a laravel job

Tags: laravel

I have a background job that fetches data from google adwords. Now my issue is when I fetch the data using a background worker.

When the response its empty what it the best thing to do is there any way to re run again or what is the best approach ?

```
public function handle()
{
    $googleService = new GoogleAds;

    $data = $googleService->report()
        ->from('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
        ->during('20170101', '20170210')
        ->select('CampaignId, Id, Criteria, IsNegative, Clicks, Ctr, Cost, Labels')
        ->getObject();

    if(!isset($data->result) || empty($data->result)){

      //what to do when no data back ? 
    }
    $this->transform->response($data);
}
```

Comment: If you run it again don't you have a risk of infinite loop? imo you should log that there was no new data i guess,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an exception, then it will go back to your queue, and the worker will try to execute it again.

When you launch your worker, there is a `--tries` parameter that indicates how many time it will try to execute before it goes to the table `failed_jobs`.

You can check the reference in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

Comment: I was thinking to throw an exception but not sure if that is the right thing to do

Comment: and technically that is not considered as a failed job, since I make the call correctly but I get empty data back !

Comment: You are the one to say if `empty data is error` or not. I don't know how the `GoogleAds` API works neither what means to return an empty result. If it does due a throttle limit, for example, you may throw an exception and set a delay to that task, and execute it again as soon the limit is over...